# Login page with scrolling horizontally only images

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create tinder like login page(onboarding). While scrolling images horizontally, the header must be the same for every UICollectionViewCell. However, but when I scroll, header doesn't stay fixed. Every time I scroll headers go left or right also. Should I use something different rather than UICollectionView ?

Imageviews must move but textview must stay fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Collectionview cell must only content imageview and not textfield.

Also if you share the UI design of what is required and developed screen then it will be more easy to give you correct answer.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j63QBB98LBc ; here after 30 seconds, my aim is something like that. Button will stay fixed every time a move to next page

Comment: Should I use ScrollView instead of CollectionView ?

Comment: From link what I understood is u need imageview to scroll but header and other textfields should not move.. if this is the case then your collection view cell should only have images. Header and textfields should be outside the collection view. So on scrolling only images will scroll and rest will stay as required. I will share demo link of this soon.

Comment: I have created a sample project. I have used pageviewcontroller to achieve the requirements. Link to sample project : https://github.com/Abhie87/OnBoardingProject

Comment: Thank you ! @Abhie